# What is this component on electric water-pump controller?

Tags: components, identification

This is an electric water-pump controller

[image: Picture1]

There is a component that I don't know what it is. it's marked as "RD". look:

[image: Picture]

In your opinion What would it be?

Comment: You appear to have not shown a component that is important. Is a moving magnet near the RD component when the PCB is in operating position? If so, what moves the magnet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely a reed <s>relay</s> switch (no coil). You can even see the thin metal contacts.

Comment: Yeah - i'm guessing there's a fixed magnet attached to some part of this device that aligns with it.

Comment: Or the reed switch is monitoring a float with magnet to prevent applying power to the heater if the water level is not high enough?

Comment: I'd say reed switch, rather than reed relay - I don't see any sign of a relay coil.  The switch would be operated by a magnet that moves near the board.

Comment: I have seen this used to turn on special diagnostics / setup modes.

Comment: @PeterBennett: Agreed.